# How to debug for each loop using index?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a Java for each loop like this :

```
public void doManyThings() {
    for (Thing thing : arrayListOfThings) {
        thing.doThing();
    }
}
```

In Intellij IDEA, I want to set a conditional breakpoint which breaks at a particular index. How do I do this, without adding an index in the code or making any other modification to the code ?

Comment: The `for-each` loop **hides** the iterator (and the index). The answer is, as you seem to reject, using a traditional loop with an explicit index. Why are you resistant to adding an index?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I want to know how I can do it without modifying the code. I prefer to avoid modification whenever feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the members of `arrayListOfThings` are unique, then you could use a conditional breakpoint something like :

```
thing == arrayListOfThings.get(3)
```